# Parameterizing/Extracting Discriminated Union cases

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Currently i'm working in a game and use Event/Observables much, one thing i run into was to eliminate some redundant code, and i didn't found a way to do it. To explain it, let's assume we have following DU and an Observable for this DU.

```
type Health =
    | Healed
    | Damaged
    | Died
    | Revived

let health = Event<Health>()
let pub    = health.Publish
```

I have a lot of this kind of structures. Having all "Health" Messages grouped together is helpfull and needed in some situations, but in some situations i only care for a special Message. Because that is still often needed i use `Observable.choose` to separate those message. I have then code like this.

```
let healed = pub |> Observable.choose (function 
    | Healed -> Some ()
    | _      -> None
)

let damaged = pub |> Observable.choose (function
    | Damaged -> Some ()
    | _       -> None
)
```

Writing this kind of code is actually pretty repetitive and annoying. I have a lot of those types and messages. So one "rule" of functional programming is "Parametrize all the things". So i wrote a function `only` to just help me.

```
let only msg pub = pub |> Observable.choose (function
    | x when x = msg -> Some ()
    | _              -> None
)
```

With such a function in place, now the code becomes a lot shorter and less annoying to write.

```
let healed  = pub |> only Healed
let damaged = pub |> only Damaged
let died    = pub |> only Died
let revived = pub |> only Revived
```

**EDIT:**
The important thing to note. `healed`, `damaged`, `died`, `revived` are now of type `IObservable<unit>` not `IObservable<Health>`. The idea is not just to separate the messages. This can be easily achieved with `Observable.filter`. The idea is that the the data for each case additional get extracted. For DU case that don't carry any additional data this is easy, as i only have to write `Some ()` in the `Observable.choose` function.

But this only works, as long the different cases in a DU don't expect additional values. Unlucky i also have a lot of cases that carry additional information. For example instead of `Healed` or `Damaged` i have `HealedBy of int`. So a message also contains additional how much something got healed. What i'm doing is something like this, in this case.

```
let healedBy = pub |> Observable.choose (function
    | HealedBy x -> Some x
    | _          -> None
)
```

But what i really want is to write it something like this

```
let healedBy = pub |> onlyWith HealeadBy
```

What i'm expecting is to get an `Observable<int>`. And i didn't found any way how to do it. I cannot write a function like `only` above. because when i try to evaluate `msg` inside a Pattern Matching then it is just seen as a variable to Pattern Match all cases. I cannot say something like: "Match on the case inside the variable."

I can check if a variable is of some specific case. I can do `if x = HealedBy then` but after that, i cannot extract any kind of data from `x`. What i'm really need is something like an "unsecure" extracting like option for example provide it with `optional.Value`. Does there exists any way to implement such a "onlyWith" function to remove the boilerplate?

---

**EDIT:**
The idea is not just separating the different messages. This can be achieved through `Observable.filter`. Here `healedBy` is of type `IObservable<int>` NOT `IObservable<Health>` anymore. The big idea is to separate the messages **AND** extract the data it carries along **AND** doing it without much boilerplate. I already can separate and extract it in one go with `Observable.choose` currently. As long as a case don't have any additional data i can use the `only` function to get rid of the boilerplate.

But as soon a case has additional data i'm back at writing the repetitive `Observable.Choose` function and do all the Pattern Matching again. The thing is currently i have code like this.

```
let observ = pub |> Observable.choose (function 
    | X (a) -> Some a
    | _     -> None
)
```

And i have this kind of stuff for a lot of messages and different types. But the only thing that changes is the "X" in it. So i obviously want to Parameterize "X" so i don't have to write the whole construct again and again. At best it just should be

```
let observ = anyObservable |> onlyWith CaseIWantToSeparate
```

But the new Observable is of the type of the specific case i separated. Not the type of the DU itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour it appears you are looking for doesn't exist, it works fine in your first example because you can always consistently return a `unit option`.

```
let only msg pub = 
    pub |> Observable.choose (function
        | x when x = msg -> Some ()
        | _              -> None)
```

Notice that this has type: `'a -> IObservable<'a> -> IObservable<unit>`

Now, let's imagine for the sake of creating a clear example that I define some new DU that can contain several types:

```
type Example =
    |String of string
    |Int of int
    |Float of float
```

Imagine, as a thought exercise, I now try to define some general function that does the same as the above.  What might its type signature be?

```
Example -> IObservable<Example> -> IObservable<???>
```

**`???`** can't be any of the concrete types above because the types are all different, nor can it be a generic type for the same reason.

Since it's impossible to come up with a sensible type signature for this function, that's a pretty strong implication that this isn't the way to do it.

The core of the problem you are experiencing is that you can't decide on a return type at runtime, returning a data type that can be of several different possible but defined cases is precisely the problem discriminated unions help you solve.

As such, your only option is to explicitly handle each case, you already know or have seen several options for how to do this.  Personally, I don't see anything too horrible about defining some helper functions to use:

```
let tryGetHealedValue = function
    |HealedBy hp -> Some hp
    |None -> None

let tryGetDamagedValue = function
    |DamagedBy dmg -> Some dmg
    |None -> None
```

Comment: Thanks, at least one answer that really answered the question. Even if that question is "It cannot be done". The horrible part is, if you have a lot of message types then it gets horrible. Try to write 30+ "tryGetXYZValue" functions that are basically all the same and just differ by the Union Case to match, and you will also look into how to get rid of that boilerplate.

Comment: @SidBurn I do sympathise, one of the libraries I am working on has a lot of tedious pattern matching of similar forms and I know it's only going to get worse as I expand it.  On the plus side, at least it's a nice type-safe pattern and it should be easy to test.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't feel like you can get your `onlyWith` function without making some significant changes elsewhere. You can't really generalize the function you pass in for the `HealedBy` case while staying within the type system (I suppose you could cheat with reflection).

One thing that seems like a good idea would be to introduce a wrapper for the `Healed` type instead of having a `HealedBy` type:

```
type QuantifiedHealth<'a> = { health: Health; amount: 'a }
```

and then you can have an `onlyWith` function like this:

```
let onlyWith msg pub =
    pub |> Observable.choose (function
        | { health = health; amount = amount } when health = msg -> Some amount
        | _ -> None)
```

I guess you can even go one step further while you're at it, and parameterize your type by both the label and the amount types to make it truly generic:

```
type Quantified<'label,'amount> = { label: 'label; amount: 'amount }
```

**Edit**: To reitarate, you keep this DU:

```
type Health =
    | Healed
    | Damaged
    | Died
    | Revived
```

Then you make your health event - **still a single one** - use the `Quantified` type:

```
let health = Event<Quantified<Health, int>>()
let pub    = health.Publish
```

You can trigger the event with messages like `{ label = Healed; amount = 10 }` or `{ label = Died; amount = 0 }`. And you can use the `only` and `onlyWith` functions to filter and project the event stream to `IObservable<unit>` and `IObservable<int>` respectively, without introducing any boilerplate filtering functions.

```
 let healed  : IObservable<int>  = pub |> onlyWith Healed
 let damaged : IObservable<int>  = pub |> onlyWith Damaged
 let died    : IObservable<unit> = pub |> only Died
 let revived : IObservable<unit> = pub |> only Revived
```

The label alone is enough to differentiate between records representing "Healed" and "Died" cases, you no longer need to walk around the payload you would have in your old "HealedBy" case. Also, if you now add a `Mana` or `Stamina` DU, you can reuse the same generic functions with `Quantified<Mana, float>` type etc.

Does this make sense to you?

Arguably it's slightly contrived compared to a simple DU with "HealedBy" and "DamagedBy", but it does optimize the use case that you care for.

Comment: I currently don't see how i save any boilerplate with your solution. Currently i have a DU with 4 cases, and i have to write 4 times the same `Observable.choose` that only differs on the message to separate them. Now in your case i have to write a Quantified type, at some point map it to the Quantified type. If i use the generic version i have to create a quantified type for every case. How does that overall remove boilerplate? It seems i'm even writing more code as before.

Comment: You're a whiny one, eh? What I suggest here is a way to restructure your domain model so that you can have a generic `onlyWith` function that also extracts the data associated with the message. So you can write `let healedBy = pub |> onlyWith Healed` and get your `IObservable<int>` out of it. I don't see how it produces more boilerplate than it removes.

Comment: Why being aggressive? I ask you friendly to explain how your solution helps. As currently, i'm, not able to see how to make it better with your proposed solution. The Domain Model i have is 4 "Events". They are just grouped together so all different Health messages are contained in one type. That is often what i need. So how should replacing it with a Record help? I for example also have "Died" and "Revived" as events in it. How do you represents those notifications with your Record?

Comment: I'd represent them the same way as instances of `Quantified<Health, int>` (arguably for "Died" case the only sensible amount might be 0). The idea is to untangle the case label from the payload, so it can be used to filter the stream of events, as this is what you originally asked for.

Comment: So you make your health event an `Event<Quantified<Health, int>>`. Maybe that's the part you're missing.

Comment: Ah okay i think i understand now what you mean. But that doesn't make much sense to me. I'm creating a `Health` type to group them, so i only have a single source event to Trigger, not multiple. In your case i have one event for basically every case. If that is what i wanted i also could use `let healed = Event<int>()` directly. Or probably i still don't see the purpose of your `Quantified` type.

Comment: These comments are getting drawn out. Check the edit.

Comment: Yes, i now understand what you meant, the problem is that every case can also have different types. I have some messages that sometimes send an `int`, some other cases send complex objects, records and so on, all being part of the same DU. That's also why i had problems understanding your case. Because even a generic type like `Quantified<Health,int>` is not enough. Look at the answer from `TheInnerLight`. His `Example` DU are the kind of of DUs i have to deal with. That i picked an example where every case just have an int was just a coincidence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104113/discussion-between-scrwtp-and-sid-burn).

Answer (score 1):

The usual route in these situations is to define predicates for cases, and then use them for filtering:

```
type Health = | Healed | Damaged | Died | Revived

let isHealed = function | Healed -> true | _ -> false
let isDamaged = function | Damaged -> true | _ -> false
let isDied = function | Died -> true | _ -> false
let isRevived = function | Revived -> true | _ -> false

let onlyHealed = pub |> Observable.filter isHealed
```

---

**UPDATE**
Based on your comment: if you want to not only filter messages, but also unwrap their data, you can define similar `option`-typed functions and use them with `Observable.choose`:

```
type Health = | HealedBy of int | DamagedBy of int | Died | Revived

let getHealed = function | HealedBy x -> Some x | _ -> None
let getDamaged = function | DamagedBy x -> Some x | _ -> None
let getDied = function | Died -> Some() | _ -> None
let getRevived = function | Revived -> Some() | _ -> None

let onlyHealed = pub |> Observable.choose getHealed  // : Observable<int>
let onlyDamaged = pub |> Observable.choose getDamaged  // : Observable<int>
let onlyDied = pub |> Observable.choose getDied  // : Observable<unit>
```

Comment: But then `onlyHealed` is still of type `Health` and all observables that subscribe to `onlyHealed` still have to Pattern Match against the message. But if that is the case, i don't even need the filtering to begin with.

Comment: So it was in your original solution, I just kept the semantics of it. But ok, if you also want to unwrap the data, that is also doable, I've updated the answer.

Comment: No, my original solution has `let healed` that is an `Observable<unit>` that only triggers when `Healed` was sent. If you subscribe to `healed` you don't need to Pattern Match anymore. In `HealedBy` you have `int` and you don't need to Pattern Match anymore. Your update is actually identical to the solution i already have. I already use `Observable.choose`. The only thing you do is to extract the inline `function` in its own `let` binding. But i want to get rid of the boilerplate of the `getHealed`, `getDamaged` functions. Not just extract them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to do this I think. This might be pretty slow:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

type Health =
    | Healed of int
    | Damaged  of int
    | Died 
    | Revived 

let GetUnionCaseInfo (x:'a) = 
    match FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(x, typeof<'a>) with
    | case, [||] -> (case.Name, null )
    | case, value -> (case.Name, value.[0] )


let health = Event<Health>()
let pub    = health.Publish

let only msg pub = pub |> Observable.choose (function
    | x when x = msg -> Some(snd (GetUnionCaseInfo(x)))
    | x when fst (GetUnionCaseInfo(x)) = fst (GetUnionCaseInfo(msg)) 
                    -> Some(snd (GetUnionCaseInfo(x)))
    | _              -> None
)

let healed  = pub |> only (Healed 0)
let damaged = pub |> only (Damaged 0)
let died    = pub |> only Died
let revived = pub |> only Revived

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let healing = Healed 50
    let damage = Damaged 100
    let die = Died
    let revive = Revived

    healed.Add (fun i ->
            printfn "We healed for %A." i)

    damaged.Add (fun i ->
            printfn "We took %A damage." i)

    died.Add (fun i ->
            printfn "We died.")

    revived.Add (fun i ->
            printfn "We revived.")

    health.Trigger(damage)
    //We took 100 damage.
    health.Trigger(die)
    //We died.
    health.Trigger(healing)
    //We healed for 50.    
    health.Trigger(revive)
    //We revived.

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: The problem is not just the separation of the messages. That can easily achieved without reflection by just comparing the msg. The idea is also the extraction. For example in your code you still have to Pattern Match like `healed.Add (function | Healed x -> (* DoWithX *) | _ -> (* Else *) )` but if that is the case, i also could do that directly on `pub` `pub.Add (function | Healed x -> (* DoWithX *) | _ -> (* Else *) )`

Comment: Gotcha. So when you trigger the healing event you want to return the data? I edited my answer. I think it should do what you want... It isn't pretty though...